# Deserializing a generic type using gson in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, gson

I have a generic type Animal implemented as a sealed class that can be a Dog or a Cat.

```
sealed class Animal(val typeOfAnimal: String) {
  data class Dog(val barkVolume: Int): Animal("dog")
  data class Cat(val hasStripes: Boolean): Animal("cat")
}
```

According to http://jansipke.nl/serialize-and-deserialize-a-list-of-polymorphic-objects-with-gson/ you can deserialize an Animal by registering a RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory

```
val animalAdapterFactory = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.of(Animal::class.java, "typeOfAnimal").registerSubtype(Dog::class.java, Dog::class.java.qualifiedName).registerSubtype(Cat::class.java, Cat::class.java.qualifiedName)
gson = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(animalAdapterFactory)
```

But if I try to deserialize an animal that looks like

```
jsonStr = "{barkVolume: 100}"
gson.fromJson(json, Animal::class.java)
```

RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory complains that it can't deserialize Animal as it does not dfine a field named "typeOfAnimal"

To my understanding typeOfAnimal is a field you add to differentiate the subtypes and not something you need in the json you are deserializing.  Because my json is really coming from an api I cannot add the field.

Comment: looks like you're using "json" as a function arg instead of "jsonStr"

Answer (score -1):

`typeOfAnimal` is required because gson must know which class should choose to deserialize your json. There is no way to guess the type, but you can [implement your own deserializator](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-advanced-custom-deserialization-basics). In a custom deserializator you can implement logic such as:

```kotlin
if (jsonObject.get("barkVolume") != null) {
    // retun Dog object
}
```